# UITableViewCell auto-layout issue with centerXAnchor set

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to build an messaging interface and faced this issue. As this is messaging app, a message bubble either align leading or trailing. I thought doing this kind if thing, creating a subview called `bubbleView` which will align itself using a computed variable called `bubbleViewCenterXConstraintValue`.

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        print(frame, bubbleView.frame)
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}

private var bubbleViewCenterXConstraintValue: CGFloat {
    print(UIScreen.main.bounds.width, contentView.frame.width, bubbleView.frame.width, ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - bubbleView.bounds.width) / 2))
    return ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - bubbleView.bounds.width) / 2)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    backgroundColor = .clear
    contentView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    
    bubbleView.addSubviews(messageLabel, hourLabel)
    
    messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.topAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    
    hourLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    hourLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    hourLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    
    contentView.addSubview(bubbleView)
    
    bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    bubbleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
    bubbleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: bubbleViewCenterXConstraintValue).isActive = true
    bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: availableMaxWidth).isActive = true
}
```

However, whenever `bubbleViewCenterXConstraintValue` is called the frame of `bubbleView` is zero so it is miscalculating my logic. Logic does not include left or right alignment right now, it just tries to align to right.

When I looked into those print results I realized another weird thing. Width of `contentView` is 320 which is not equal to the `UIScreen.main.bounds.width(390)`.

```
(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
390.0 320.0 0.0 195.0
(0.0, 0.0, 390.0, 100.66666666666667) (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 390.0, 100.66666412353516) (243.66666666666666, 4.0, 292.6666666666667, 92.66666666666667)
(0.0, 0.0, 390.0, 100.66666412353516) (243.66666666666666, 4.0, 292.6666666666667, 92.66666666666667)
```

I need a way to make those auto-layout code to update whenever the frame of `bubbleView` is set. Because I know that if its width would be 292 initially this code would work. I tried the current non working solution `setNeedsLayout()` and overriding `layoutSubviews` but that did not work too.

I know I am missing something and the solution is just right there, however I cant see right now and need some help.

Appreciated in advance.

Note: Also looked for a solution in the site could not find anything similar. If you think this is duplicate feel free to tell me or get in action.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you want to put the bubble onto the screen aligned to the right edge by moving the centre point to the right by half the different in width of the bubble and screen.   While the logic makes sense in theory, this seems a strange way to do this; plus, as you realise, the bounds are valid until autolayout has completed so it won't work in practice.  Was there a reason for the decision to use the views bounds rather than all in autolayout?  And any reason you are trying to offset the centre rather than using trailing constraints?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am using bounda because width of bubbles are limited but can change. And as an answer for the second question, I just thought it will be easier this way rather than having two constraints -leading and trailing- and activating/deactivating them respectively

Comment: I missed out an important word above:  bounds are *not* valid until autolayout has completed (and if all layout is using autolayout, not then either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have thought the easier way to do this would be to set leading and trailing constraints for the bubble.  This would make it easy to decide which side of the screen to align to.  You could also use autolayout for the width parameter, using a multiplier based on parent view width to make it cope with any size screen.

I'm not going to work it into your code as it would be too long, but hopefully the below example function will show the principles I'd recommend:

```
   func addBubble(alignLeft: Bool, offset: CGFloat) {
      let bubble = UIView()
      bubble.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
      let parentView = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide  //your parent view may be different
      parentView.addSubview(bubble)

      bubble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      
      //quick and dirty top and bottom constraints for the example
      bubble.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor, constant: 10 + offset).isActive = true
      bubble.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor, constant: 40 + offset).isActive = true

      //set the width of the bubble proportional to the size of the parent view
      bubble.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2/3).isActive = true

      // implement the left or right alignment
      if alignLeft {
         bubble.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
      } else {
         bubble.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
      }
   }
```

This way all you have to do is anchor the bubble's sub views to the bubbles top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints and they will also resize with the bubble to cope with all screen sizes.

Comment: I solved it using your suggestion. I handled it in `UITableViewCell` class.

Comment: Though I started to think `UICollectionView` maybe would be more convenient way to do such task

Comment: Not knowing the app design it’s a bit hard to say, but I’d probably just use a scroll view and keep appending bubbles as subviews. The concept is the same wherever though.